# pdf file corrupted when try to forward mail from thunderbird/outlook

Tags: php, email, pdf, tcpdf, thunderbird

- Generated pdf with tcpdf
- It gives proper output, when open it directly to browser
- when try to send mail instead of download to local machine, in first occurance it open properly
- Forward mail from thunderbird to other user, that pdf file is corrupted and 
  showing message like : 
  "Adobe reader could not open 'nsmail-3.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or 
  because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Sample code to send mail is

```
$fileName = 'output.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdfObj->Output('output.pdf', 'E'); 
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);

$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());
$headers = 'From: Sender <test@testmail.com>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$separator.'"';

$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Type:text/html;Charset=ISO-8859-1'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.$eol.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'message content text'.$eol;

$eol = "\r\n";
$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'.$fileName.'"'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName.$eol;
$mailMessage .= $attachment.$eol;
$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.'--';
mail('test@testmail.com', $toEmailid, $subject, $mailMessage, $headers);
```

**can anyone suggest where I am wrong in above code ?**
**or its thunderbird or outlook related issue ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Used alternate solution to send pdf file in mail that is, store file on server, send email with attachment, remove file from server after mail send.

Sample code

```
$fileName = 'output.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdfObj->Output(SERVERPATH.'/output.pdf', 'F');

$filename = 'output.pdf';
$file = $naTmpPath.'/'.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());
$headers = 'From: Sender <test@testmail.com>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$separator.'"';

$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Type:text/html;Charset=ISO-8859-1'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.$eol.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'message content text'.$eol;

$eol = "\r\n";
$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'.$fileName.'"'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.$eol;
$mailMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName.$eol;
$mailMessage .= $attachment.$eol;
$mailMessage .= '--'.$separator.'--';
mail('test@testmail.com', $toEmailid, $subject, $mailMessage, $headers);
```